# UICollectionview - blink when move item

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, ios11

I want to reorder my cells in my UICollectionView. But when I drop my item, the "cellForItemAt" method is called and this will cause the cell to flash (See image below).

What should I do to avoid this behavior ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

[image]

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    private let cellIdentifier = "cell"
    private let cells = [""]

    private var longPressGesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleLongGesture(gesture:)))
        collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
    }

    //Selectors
    @objc func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        switch(gesture.state) {

        case .began:
            guard let selectedIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: collectionView)) else {
                break
            }
            collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
        case .changed:
            collectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: gesture.view!))
        case .ended:
            collectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
        default:
            collectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
        }
    }

}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canMoveItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    }
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to call **endInteractiveMovement** in **perfomBatchUpdates**.

But whenever **endInteractiveMovement** triggered, **cellForRow** called. So cell will be refreshed and new cell will added(check with random color extension). To secure that, you need to save selectedCell in variable. And return that cell when **endInteractiveMovement** called.

Declare currentCell in ViewController

```
var isEnded: Bool = true
var currentCell: UICollectionViewCell? = nil
```

Store selected cell in variable when gesture began & call **endInteractiveMovement** in **performBatchUpdates**.

So, your handleLongGesture func look like below:

```
//Selectors
@objc func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    switch(gesture.state) {

    case .began:

        guard let selectedIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: collectionView)) else {
            break
        }

        isEnded = false
        //store selected cell in currentCell variable
        currentCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)

        collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)

    case .changed:
        collectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: gesture.view!))
    case .ended:

        isEnded = true
        collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
            self.collectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
        }) { (result) in
            self.currentCell = nil
        }

    default:
        isEnded = true
        collectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
    }
}
```

Also need to change **cellForRow**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if currentCell != nil && isEnded {
        return currentCell!
   } else {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = .random
        return cell
    }
}
```

**TIP**

Use random color extension for better testing

```
extension UIColor {
    public class var random: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: CGFloat(drand48()), green: CGFloat(drand48()), blue: CGFloat(drand48()), alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you have multiple sections.
Lets take array of array

```
var data: [[String]] = [["1","2"],
                        ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"],
                        ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15"]]
```

Then you need to maintain data when reordering

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {

    print("\(sourceIndexPath) -> \(destinationIndexPath)")

    let movedItem = data[sourceIndexPath.section][sourceIndexPath.item]
    data[sourceIndexPath.section].remove(at: sourceIndexPath.item)
    data[destinationIndexPath.section].insert(movedItem, at: destinationIndexPath.item)

}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: helped me a lot as well!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call

```
collectionView.reloadItems(at: [sourceIndexPath, destinationIndexPath])
```

right after all your updates (drag and drop animation) are done.
For example call it after `performBatchUpdates`. It will remove blinking.